# Simple condition with ProjectTo doesn't work

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, ef-core-3.1

I have the problem with `ProjectTo`.
I have that Select map:

```
var posts = await appContext.Posts
    .Select(x => new PostListReadModel()
    {
        IsAnonymous = x.IsAnonymous,
        Publisher = !x.IsAnonymous ?
            new PostPublisherReadModel()
            {
                Id = x.PublisherId,
                Nick = x.Publisher.Nick,
                PhoneNumber = x.Publisher.PhoneNumber,
                Avatar = x.Publisher.Avatar
            } :
            null
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

As you can see, I have a mapping condition for the `Publisher` property. Very simple condition.
It translates to sql like this:

```
SELECT p.IsAnonymous, NOT (p.IsAnonymous), p.PublisherId, u.Nick, u.PhoneNumber, i.Id, i.DateCreated, i.DateUpdated, i.FileName
      FROM posts AS p
      INNER JOIN users AS u ON p.PublisherId = u.Id
      LEFT JOIN images AS i ON u.AvatarId = i.Id
```

And it works.

Now, I want to use `ProjectTo`. And I have a map configuration like this:

```
CreateMap<User, PostPublisherReadModel>();

CreateMap<Post, PostListReadModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsAnonymous, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsAnonymous))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Publisher, opt => opt.Condition(src => !src.IsAnonymous))
    .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

It translates to sql like this:

```
SELECT p.IsAnonymous, FALSE, i.Id, i.DateCreated, i.DateUpdated, i.FileName, u.Id, u.Nick, u.PhoneNumber
      FROM posts AS p
      INNER JOIN users AS u ON p.PublisherId = u.Id
      LEFT JOIN images AS i ON u.AvatarId = i.Id
```

and it naturally doesn't work.

Is it an automapper error or am i doing something wrong?
P.S.: DbProvider: Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql Version=3.1.0

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options

Comment: I have only one question: 
when will the support be?

Comment: It's not needed. You should write the condition _inside_ the `MapFrom`.